# UISegmentedControl with square corners

Tags: ios, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol, cornerradius

I would like to modify UISegmentedControl with a subclass to remove the rounded corners. I can't seem to set the cornerRadius. Making the SegmentedControl wider than the screen (and therefor "chop" off the corners) is not an option since I have 4 or 5 segments and they would then vary in size.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the width of the segments (using [setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:)) so you can easily make the left and right end segments larger (say 10px larger) than the others and then you can crop off 10px from either end and have square corners.  You don't have to make it larger than the screen width, instead put it inside a UIView and use it to crop the ends.

On the other hand just could just make your own segmented control using a set of custom UIButtons inside a UIControl.

Comment: decided to go with the 10px version, since you don't have excess segments and indexes.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) how do you use a UIView to crop the ends. 2) how would you go about making your own segmented control using UIButtons inside of a UIControl.

Comment: @ladookie 1) make the control wider than the parent view, set clipsToBounds on the parent view, 2) create a subclass of UIControl that contains an array of UIButtons and implement the methods of UISegmentedControl (just the ones you need) using the buttons to make your subclass behave like a UISegmentedControl except for the rounded corners.

Answer (score 37):

To make the corner square use the following code:

```
segmentContrl.layer.borderColor=*anycolor*.CGColor;
segmentContrl.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
segmentContrl.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
```

Comment: this worked for my purposes, but didn't need the cornerRadius part.

Comment: Then ignore cornerRadius.

Comment: This is the only non-hack.

Answer (score 15):

One alternative, if "cropping" part of the first and last segment is problematic, may be to crop the entire first and last segment (which you've made dummy unused segments). That way you can still keep a common size for every segment.

Comment: simply elegant. The advantage of this, is that you visually still have the vertical lines at the edge.

Comment: Nice!  In layout subviews I take the width of the segmented control, get the width of one segment by dividing the number of segments, set the width of the mask view to (num segments - 2) * width + 2 (left right border) and I'm golden!

Answer (score 11):

Just use the built in customization methods and set a background image for each segment state.  This will override the border entirely.  If the background images are square, then your segmented control will appear square. Use the following code for each segment state you want to customize.

`[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"square-background-image-selected"]
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected
                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: You might need to provide a background image for normal control state as well otherwise the background image for selected control state won't be applied

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative to accomplish this in interface builder:

Drag a UIView object to your UIViewController, this may be a subview of your UIView.

Drag a UISegmentedControl as a subview of your UIView.  The segmented control should now be indented in your list UIViewController objects. (see screenshot below).

Resize the SegementedControl so that its' frame is outside the boundaries of your UIView object.  In my case I set the frame of the SegementedControl to X = -10 and added +20 to the width of the SegementedControl so that the total width of the segmented control because 20 greater then the UIView object. (hopefully, the screen shot below helps).

I also adjusted the following settings for the UIView object and SegmentedControl:
UIView: check Clip SubViews, uncheck AutoResize Subviews.
SegementedControl: uncheck Clip SubViews, uncheck AutoResize Subviews.

[image]

Comment: This solution is clean and simple and works very well for the case where you have exactly two equal sized segments.

Comment: Very simple solution, and also works if it is created programmatically - so well done on the brilliant idea!