# Square Corners UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there any solution to make `UIsegmentedControl` with Square corner by programming?
Please help!!!

Comment: You may get your answer here :- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739173/uisegmentedcontrol-with-square-corners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this open source control. it will work fine for you. [`https://github.com/oettam/MCSegmentedControl`](https://github.com/oettam/MCSegmentedControl)

Comment: Hi Muhammad Noman, Thanks for the link which you have provide, it has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can set background images for the segments that will override the border entirely.  If the background images are square, then your segmented control will appear square. Use the following code for each segment state you want to custumise.

`[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"square-background-image-selected"]
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected
                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`